# How to clean up old build on Cloudbee and Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-job-dsl

I want to schedule a job to clean old build so I have configure the below scripts but its working at Jenkins script console and not for Jenkins job configuration. While running the job I am getting below error:

> Processing provided DSL script
>   ERROR: (script, line 5) No such property: Jenkins for class: script
>   Finished: FAILURE.my scripts is"

Code:

```
MAX_BUILDS = 2
for (job in Jenkins.instance.items) {
  println job.name

  def recent = job.builds.limit(MAX_BUILDS)

  for (build in job.builds) {
    if (!recent.contains(build)) {
      println "Preparing to delete: " + build
      build.delete()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins script console automatically imports the packages `jenkins.*`, `jenkins.model.*`, `hudson.*`, and `hudson.model.*`. But Job DSL does not automatically import these packages, you have to do that at the beginning of your script

```
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*

// your script
```

But it would be cleaner to just import the classes that you need, e.g. `jenkins.model.Jenkins`

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

// your script
```

Comment: thanks daspilker can u pls help me on above script how to exclude multibranch project because now my  scripts is fine but multi branch project throwing error